# Are there any ways to exploit this feature that creates a copy of a magical weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review

I am currently working on a bit of homebrew which includes a rule, which currently has the wording

> If your bonded weapon has the light property, you can create two copies of it instead. Both copies are considered the same weapon for the purposes of charges or other limits on the use of its features.

Are there any strange exploits available that I should be aware of and perhaps include verbiage to avoid?

Comment: Is this meant to be different in terms of game mechanics from "you can choose to use your bonus action to deliver a single attack with your bonded weapon"?

Comment: it's meant to follow normal rules for two weapon fighting, whichever version of them you are using

Comment: Is this based on the bonded weapon Eldritch Knight feature?

Comment: Closer to a warlock's Pact Weapon

Comment: Can you include more of the surrounding text? Based on your term "bonded weapon", I think everyone is assuming you mean the feature from the Eldritch Knight. If that is not the case, that may change or invalidate answers.

Answer (score 15):

### Make a "duplicate", not "two copies"

The fighter always summons the original weapon they bonded with, not a copy of it. By making "two copies", you end up with three weapons: the original bonded weapon and the "two copies".

### There is no duration

How long do these copies last?

### Is the duplicate created in the same bonus action summoning?

When you summon your bonded weapon as a bonus action, do you also summon the duplicate at the same time? What if you already have your bonded weapon out? Do you have to lose it to summon two weapons, or can you just summon the duplicate? If so, how long does that take? Another bonus action?

### Since one copy affects another, you can bypass Action Economy in the copies

For instance, if I have a [Dagger of Venom](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4613-dagger-of-venom), a light weapon:

> You can use an action to cause thick, black poison to coat the blade. The poison remains for 1 minute or until an attack using this weapon hits a creature.

So one action would cause both blades to become venomous. This will work with any weapon that has a feature that normally takes an action (or bonus action) to perform. Use one, get one free.

### Can I give my duplicate to a friend?

Nothing in the rules say that the bonded weapon only works for the fighter. So can I duplicate the Dagger of Venom (no attunement required) and give the second to an ally? What if they use their action to venomize the blade? Now the fighter has full use of the dagger and not spent their action.

### Speaking of attunement, what if the bonded weapon requires attunement?

Say you have a [Scimitar of Speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4752-scimitar-of-speed) as your bonded weapon. It requires attunement in order to be of value. When I make a duplicate, am I automatically attuned to it also? What if that attunement puts me past my limit of spaces? Do I lose attunement to one of my other items or can I now have more attunement slots than normally allowed?

Comment: I suspect the action economy question could be answered by answering the related "What would happen if you had two of these objects?" question. And the answer as far as I can tell would be "no, you need separate actions for the two weapons" and "no, you don't get two attacks per bonus action/two bonus actions".

Comment: @biziclop, actually having two of something is different. In this case, the duplicate is "linked" to the original. As the OP states, _"considered the same weapon for the purposes of charges or other limits on the use of its features"_. So if I use a charge from one, it reduces the charge from both. Having two similar items does not work that way.

Comment: You definitely don't get two bonus action attacks from dual-wielding scimitars of speed. You've only got one bonus action per turn, and the ability only grants one attack, not two.

Comment: @nick012000m yeah, I removed it as a bad example

Comment: @MivaScott I agree, they are different, that's why I said it's a related question. But answering it can help us guide in answering the real question.

Comment: For the action economy: I would read the description by OP as yes, one action poisons both blades. But after one of them is used in an attack the poison is used up on both copies. So you poison only once.

Comment: @quarague Yes, that makes perfect sense. It's slightly better than poisoning only one in that whichever one will hit first, it will have the poison, but that's not too big an advantage on this level.

Comment: @quarague, I'm envisioning the fighter hand the duplicate to a minion who uses up their action to poison the blade, so the fighter would have all of their attacks always available. So it would look like--Bonus action: summon dupe, Free action: hand dupe to someone, regular action: attack/extra attack. At some point the someone activates the blade on their turn. Fighter's next turn: attack with a poisoned blade.

Answer (score 5):

### Probably best to specify that "once per turn" effects still only happen once.

For example, the Sword of Wounding has the following feature.

> Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack using this magic weapon, you can wound the target. At the start of each of the wounded creature's turns, it takes 1d4 necrotic damage for each time you've wounded it [...].

So having two swords would stack up the debuff twice as fast.

Any weapons that don't specify this "once per turn" clause are probably fine, since their effects are probably per attack, and that already varies per character (a Fighter will attack 4x, while a Rogue only once).

Comment: Or, at least, specify whether "once per turn" effects can happen multiple times; if this is an 18th level ability, once per weapon might be appropriate.

Comment: Seeing as both copies are the same weapon, they share the "cooldown" for "once per turn" effects - that is my intent, at least.

Answer (score 5):

The duration of the copies needs to be specified, or some other limitation on their use needs to be provided. Without such a limitation, there's a clearly-unintended, rules-lawyer-ey interpretation of the rule as-written that allows for creating infinite copies of a bonded weapon (possibly requiring the "light" property, depending on the rest of the rule) which can be sold for profit. Specifically: "I have a bonded, light weapon; I make two copies of it and sell them, then make two more copies and sell them, etc.".

The duration of the copy would depend on the type of action necessary to create the copy, whether concentration is required to maintain the copy, the desired feel of the feature, and possibly the character's level/proficiency bonus/key stat/....

Alternatively, the copies could only exist (eg.) as long as they're in the copying character's hand.

Comment: The bonded weapon only works for you, but it's a good concern to keep in mind.

Comment: @vonBoomslang you may want to post the entire bonded weapon ability text, so that you can avoid having to make comments like this, where you've already thought of something and covered it.  Plus it'll help us help you find any other weird edge cases.